# How do I prove this equality involving ceilings and max?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

For all $T \in \mathbb{N}$ the following holds, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\left \lceil \frac{k \cdot m}{n} \right \rceil + T - 1 = \max_{0 \leq i < T} \left \{ i + T \left \lceil \frac{k \cdot m - i \cdot n}{T \cdot n} \right \rceil \right \}.$$

Note: this is not homework!